# Woocommerce Shortcodes Pagination

Tags: pagination, woocommerce, product

been trying to figure out how to create a loop to support woocommerce's shortcode WITH Pagination.

Because currently, I have a project and would like to have a page with a certain product displayed, for example i have 50 sale products, using this shortcode [sale_products per_page="10"] it just displays 10 products without pagination. Any thoughts regarding this issue?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'so_28367762_pre_get_posts' );

function so_28367762_pre_get_posts( $q ) {
    // We only want to affect the main query
    if ( is_admin() || ! $q->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    $sale_page_id = 487;

    // totally modify the query on the Sale Page
    if( isset( $q->queried_object_id ) && $q->queried_object_id === $sale_page_id ) {

        $q->set( 'post_type', 'product' );
        $q->set( 'page', '' );
        $q->set( 'pagename', '' );

        if ( isset( $q->query['paged'] ) ) {
            $q->set( 'paged', $q->query['paged'] );
        }

        // Fix for verbose page rules
        if ( $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->use_verbose_page_rules ) {

            // Fix conditional Functions
            $q->is_archive           = true;
            $q->is_post_type_archive = true;
            $q->is_singular          = false;
            $q->is_page              = false;
        }

    WC()->query->product_query( $q );

    // We're on a shop page so queue the woocommerce_get_products_in_view function
    add_action( 'wp', array( WC()->query, 'get_products_in_view' ), 2);

    // And remove the pre_get_posts hook
    WC()->query->remove_product_query();
    }
}
```

Little modification and worked for me!

Comment: This is works for me. Also i've modified a bit https://woocommerce.com/document/exclude-a-category-from-the-shop-page/

Answer (score 1):

Well I took an alternative approach. What I've done is created a "page" that will be a product archive (just like the shop) except only for sale products. I'm sure if it wasn't almost midnight I could make it an option in WooCommerce, just like the store option to set the shop, my account pages, etc. But in the interest of speed I just made a page, took note of its ID and hard-coded it as `$sale_page_id`.

First, we're going to mimic what WooCommerce does when you tell it that you want the store to be on the front page of your site. Basically, we're going to hijack the query and switch it from a page into a product archive.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'so_28367762_pre_get_posts' );

function so_28367762_pre_get_posts( $q ) {
    // We only want to affect the main query
    if ( is_admin() || ! $q->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    $sale_page_id = 487;

    // totally modify the query on the Sale Page
    if( isset( $q->queried_object_id ) && $q->queried_object_id === $sale_page_id ) {

        $q->set( 'post_type', 'product' );
        $q->set( 'page', '' );
        $q->set( 'pagename', '' );

        if ( isset( $q->query['paged'] ) ) {
            $q->set( 'paged', $q->query['paged'] );
        }

        // Fix for verbose page rules
        if ( $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->use_verbose_page_rules ) {

            // Fix conditional Functions
            $q->is_archive           = true;
            $q->is_post_type_archive = true;
            $q->is_singular          = false;
            $q->is_page              = false;
        }

        WC()->query->product_query( $q );

        // We're on a shop page so queue the woocommerce_get_products_in_view function
        add_action( 'wp', array( WC()->query, 'get_products_in_view' ), 2);

        // And remove the pre_get_posts hook
        WC()->query->remove_product_query();

    }

}
```

And then we're going to modify the product query so that it only returns items that are on sale. I tried adding this directly above, *but* it didn't work since `post__in` starts from scratch/null in the `product_query()` method. I added the same conditional logic to make sure that this is only applied on this custom "sale" page.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'so_28367762_product_query' );

function so_28367762_product_query( $q ){

    $sale_page_id = 487;

    if( isset( $q->queried_object_id ) && $q->queried_object_id === $sale_page_id ) {
        $product_ids_on_sale = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();
        $q->set( 'post__in', (array) $product_ids_on_sale );
    }

}
```

If you have enough sale products, you should have pagination. The one thing I didn't get to tonight was that the page title shows up as "Shop" and the breadcrumbs think it is "Shop". I'm sure there is a way around that... tweaking the templates, etc.

Comment: Your theme's `functions.php` or a custom plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately, i got: "Error 404 - Page not found!".

Comment: I'd suggest re-saving your permalinks and if that doesn't work you need to create your own question.

Comment: No, it didn't help. I already have my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108785/woocommerce-showing-1-page-instead-of-4-pages-for-products-on-sale/

Comment: I moved the last few lines of the `so_28367762_pre_get_posts()` function inside the condition that checks you are on the sale page. This seems to resolve the issue of 404 errors on the my account page.

Comment: @helgatheviking I created a plugin and used your code, but my page shows the same content as the main shop homepage... Not the on sale products, what is wrong?

Comment: @helgatheviking - any idea how to add any custom html or css to this site? It works fine, but i cant figure out how to target only this page... Maybe a id attribute to the body tag or something else. thx

Comment: @NewUser I would just use the page ID and check `is_page($page_id)`

Comment: @helgatheviking - Any idea how to list the products in another order - at least from most sale amount to the least...? thx

Comment: @evavienna I would post a separate question, but my guess is that you'd need to modify the meta query params.

Comment: @helgatheviking . ok thx, the 'add_action( 'wp', array( WC()->query, 'get_products_in_view' ), 2);` part also dont work any more! deprecated without a replacement. I commented out this line - looks like it works...?

Comment: @evavienna well one of these days i am going to write a proper plugin for this, but today is not that day.

Answer (score 1):

Try this shortcode `[sale_products limit="10" columns="4" paginate="true"]`
know more from [woocommerce docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/)