# Woocommerce - Showing 1 page instead of 4 pages for products on sale

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I've got 44 products on sale, and when I put WooCommerce shortcodes

```
[sale_products per_page="12"]
```

I'm getting only 12 products on sale, i.e. 1 page instead of 4 pages.

What's wrong?

I'm using:
WP 4.4.1,
WC 2.5.1,
Mystile theme.

Answer (score 2):

Look at **"The ‘per_page’ Argument"** section on the [documentation](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/), it states:

> **Please note**: the ‘per_page’ shortcode argument will determine how many products are shown on a page. This will not add pagination to the shortcode.

Comment: If I remove "per_page" argument, I got the same: 12 products and 1 page, instead of 44 product and 4 pages.

Something else is wrong. What?

Comment: Removing the `per_page` argument will not make all the products visible. You'll need to add code for the pagination. The following gist might help : https://gist.github.com/klihelp/7810337

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, but I believe I'm close.

I added code in function.php with some changes, as it's mentioned in comment, and nothing happened when I use WC shortcode. But, when I list product categories or tags, I got (another one) pagination from code in function.php.

What I am missing?

Comment: What about using `per_page="-1"`? `posts_per_page` is a [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) parameter.