# Display On Sale Products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to use the method described in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28375823/235648) to create a paginated display of on sale products in my Wordpress Woocommerce site.

I have this line in my `pre_get_posts` hook: `$q->is_post_type_archive = true;`

If I keep this line as is, the page shows the 'Shop by Category' display (not the on sale items).

I discovered that if I change it to `false` it does display all the on sale items, but in an expanded view, I want to display it as a tabular product view, as in the rest of the shop.

What is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you adjust the `$sale_page_id = 487;` to suit your site?

Comment: Yep, and i also put some `echo` statements in the innermost blocks to make sure my code was actually running.

Comment: Well I had to ask. :) What version of WC are you running? My code is kind of old, it could be that it doesn't work any longer.

Answer (score 0):

1. In WordPress Admin, click Pages->Add New
   Create a page called "On Sale"
2. The Page contents should be as follows:

   [sale_products per_page="12" paginate="true"]

Voila!  You now have a page showing products on sale with pagination.